# AttributeError("module 'name' has no attribute 'def name'",)

Tags: python

I'm creating a virtual OS with different files, like `boot.py` and `Run.py`

It worked for a while until I typed this in:

```
if Run.run == 0:
        error() 
    else:
        start()
```

There is no errors saying about it like red lines or any. Now I get this error:

```
AttributeError("module 'boot' has no attribute 'bootup'",)
```

Here's the code:

`boot.py`:

```
#Imports
import Run

#Varibles
name = "PyOS"
version = 1
creator = "© Dragon Softwares"

def bootup(run):
    if Run.run == 0:
        error() 
    else:
        start()


def start():
        print("Starting PyOS")
        print("Version ", version)

def error():
    print("Please Run 'Run.py' To bootup the system")

bootup()
```

`Run.py`:

```
#Imports
import time
import boot

#Varibles
run = 0

def main():
    run = 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    boot.bootup
main()
```

Comment: Show us the command line you use to run it.

Comment: you can't copy it

Comment: You have a circular import. Don't have `boot` import `Run` and `Run` import `boot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular import. Don't have `boot` import `Run` and vice-versa.

What happens now is:

- `Run.py` is executed as the `__main__` module.

  - The line `import boot` is reached and executed.
  - `boot` has not been imported before, so `boot.py` is found and loaded to be the `boot` module.

    - The line `import Run` is reached and executed.
    - `Run` has not been imported before, so `Run.py` is found and loaded to be the `Run` module. **Note**: that `Run.py` is also used for `__main__` *does not matter here*.

      - The line `import boot` is reached and executed.
      - `boot` is already being imported, so it used to set the name `boot` in the `Run` module
      - Various other names are set in the `Run` module namespace (`run` and `main`).
      - The line `main()` is reached and executed

        - The `main()` function references `boot.bootup`, which doesn't exist yet, because the `boot` module top-level code never reached the `def bootup(run):` line.

Instead of importing `Run`, pass the `run` value as a parameter to the `boot` function:

```
def main():
    run = 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    boot.bootup(run)
```

Also, don't call `bootup()` at the end of the `boot` module. That function call will be executed *when you import `boot`*, and makes no sense there. If you want to present an error message, use a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    error()
    sys.exit(1)
```

The `if` test will only ever be true if you ran `boot.py` as the script.